# Overload File Function VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create an onclick function through ASP front end to check if a file exists, if not create it and write textbox text to it, currently getting an error on the below code saying that I cannot overload the file function, is there a better way of doing this?

**UPDATE**
The issue is the file is still open when trying to write to it which is throwing the error.

Please see below code:

```
Protected Sub Create_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim txtFile As String = "E:Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SomeProject\Templates\" & FileName.Text & ".txt"

    If File.Exists(txtFile) Then
        Response.Write("A file of that name already exists.")
    Else
        File.Create(txtFile)
        File.WriteAllText(eTemplate.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
    If File.Exists(txtFile) Then
        Response.Write("A file of that name already exists.")
    Else
        System.IO.File.Create(txtFile)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(txtFile, True)
        sw.Write(eTemplate.Text)
        sw.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception? `File.WriteAllText` isn't a logical call in your code because `File` is a static class and doesn't know you made a file, you need to call it as `File.WriteAllText(txtFile, eTemplate.Text)` see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the problem is that the file is saying that it's still in use.

Comment: You know this is checking on the web server, not on the user's computer, right?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yeah, that's fine as the file is on the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on the money, it is because it needs to be closed first.

I created a file stream instance first, created the file, closed it and then wrote to it. Put the below code in yours or write it out, but remember to correct the file path.

```
   Protected Sub Create_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim txtFile As String = "E:\wherever\" & FileName.Text & ".txt"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(txtFile) Then
        Dim message As String = "A file by this name already exists, choose another or update the existing file."

    Else
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(txtFile)
        fs.Close()
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(txtFile, True)
        sw.Write(eTemplate.Text)
        sw.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to create the file first, in fact File.WriteAllText will in effect delete the file and re-create it. [File.WriteAllText Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx): "Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten."